# In Mountain Lion why do remote shells via ssh do NOT inherit the environment of the launchd parent process?

Tags: macos, command-line, launchd, environment-variables

When logging in to my Mountain Lion Mac remotely via `ssh` I do not get the same `PATH` variable as when I open a shell locally: The local shell inherits its environment as expected from `launchd` and therefore has the PATH value I set in `/etc/launchd.conf`.

With the remote shell I hit a surprise: When I open a shell via `ssh` it does **not** inherit the environment variables set in `/etc/launchd.conf` although the related `ssh` processes all have `launchd` as their parents. Why???

A cut from a  `ps -ef` output shows:

```
UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  0     1     0   0 Mon01PM ??         9:07.07 /sbin/launchd
.
.
.
501   150     1   0 Mon01PM ??         0:17.99 /sbin/launchd
.
.
.
501 39994   150   0 Thu11AM ??         0:00.72 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
.
.
.
  0 74002     1   0  2:08PM ??         0:00.05 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
501 74005 74002   0  2:08PM ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
501 74000  9844   0  2:08PM ttys000    0:00.02 ssh bridge@bridgethegap.local
```

I can fix the issue by setting `PATH` e.g. in `.bashrc`, but I'm in search for a way to give the same `PATH` to *all* applications launched under Mountain Lion (see [In Mountain Lion how do I set the PATH environment variable...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87282/in-mountain-lion-how-do-i-set-the-path-environment-variable-unified-for-all-newl)).

So my question is: Why do remote shells via ssh do not inherit the launchd environment?

Answer (score 2):

I've looked for an answer too and eventually found a related answer to this question, [How to set system-wide environment variables on OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125040/9058).

It is a security measure, particularly to ensure secure shell users with a disabled shell, where `SHELL` is set to `/bin/false`, cannot gain unsolicited access.

One workaround is settting `PermitUserEnvironment` in your ssh config; please read security caveats in above mentioned answer before doing this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good idea: I've just tried to add this info from the other answer in - but it needs to be peer reviewed...

Comment: Peer-review passed - answer now more helpful. :-)