# Is $HOME/.MacOSX/environment.plist still used in OS X 10.9.2 for setting global environment variables?

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables

Is `$HOME/.MacOSX/environment.plist` still recognized/used in OS X 10.9.2 for setting global environment variables?

Apple's official documentation does not say explicitly it's deprecated, AFACT:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html

Some discussion threads claims it is no longer supported since 10.8:

[How to set system-wide environment variables on OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/how-to-set-system-wide-environment-variables-on-os-x-mavericks)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x/4567308#4567308

What to believe?

My experiments seem to indicate that it is not supported in 10.9.2, but I'm not sure, as I'm not familiar with `.plist` files etc. I'm trying to set `JAVA_HOME` permanently and globally for applications started by double clicking /Applications/XXX.app.

I have

```
$ more $HOME/.MacOSX/environment.plist
{
        "JAVA_HOME" = "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home";
}
```

which is edited by `open $HOME/.MacOSX/environment.plist` and following the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can yourself ensure that this file isn't anymore used with a command as simple as `ls`.

Just end your actual session, and connect back.
Open `Terminal` or `xterm`.
Run the following command:

```
$ cd ~/.MacOSX
$ ls -luT environment.plist
$
```

The output of this command will display you when this file was last opened for reading.
If it was opened by any process during your session start, you should
see it thanks to the `u` option.

To learn more about the investigation possibilities of `ls` just run:

```
$ man ls
```

BTW, your `environment.plist` file doesn't use the right syntax.
But this doesn't matter.