# Environment Variables on Mavericks

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to set an environment variable that will be accessible from both a GUI application (Pycharm) as well as from the Terminal. This variable is called PYTHONPATH.

I have tried

- [Setting the system-wide PATH environment variable in Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks?rq=1) which doesn't help me because I have to set PYTHONPATH, not PATH
- [How to set system-wide environment variables on OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/how-to-set-system-wide-environment-variables-on-os-x-mavericks?rq=1) which gave me the idea to use `launched.conf` but adding

  ```
  setenv PYTHONPATH ~/Documents/CrowdSurfer
  ```

  doesn't seem to have the desired effect. Maybe I got the syntax wrong here?

Can anyone give me a step by step guide of how to do this correctly on Mavericks?

Comment: Which of the questions here have yo tried and how did they fail - note just look at ones for Mavericks e.g. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks?rq=1 or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/how-to-set-system-wide-environment-variables-on-os-x-mavericks?rq=1 etc. We want to have one question for this not multiple with different answers

Comment: Which GUI application needs to get a variable from the filesystem?

Comment: The first link specific details how to set the PATH variable, a very specific environment variable, but unfortunately very different from a generic environment variable like PYTHONPATH. The second like is more helpful. He says that launched.conf is still supported. This is good news and is one of the files that I tried setting previously. Perhaps my syntax is wrong. Can anyone verify it? Here is what my file looks like: setenv PYTHONPATH ~/Documents/CrowdSurfer

Comment: Until your accounts get merged, just edit the post to explain how the linked answers don't make sense or solve your specific issue. No need to tack on edit: at the end of the post - just make the words flow with the new data included as best fits.

Comment: Also for PYTHONPATH a better way is use Python specific setups e.g. vurtualenv

Answer (score 2):

At this point in time (2022, Montrey) most hacks are not working. But the good news is that you can use `launchctl` in your shell, either explicitly (and until reboot)

```
launchctl setenv LANG "sv_SE"
launchctl setenv PATH `echo $PATH`
```

or in a script in your `.bashrc`.

There are of course a couple of ways to make such a command run a startup too.

NOTE: of course you cannot change environment variables for already running apps.

Answer (score 1):

Check your current PYTHONPATH setting by opening /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and typing the following command and hit the return key:

```
  echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Try this alternate syntax in Terminal.app to see if it sets your PYTHONPATH correctly. Recheck the result with the above command again. If so, put the line in your ~/.bash_profile (although a file in /etc/paths.d/ with just the PATH, no commands, ought to set this system-wide).

```
  export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH\ : $USER/Documents/CrowdSurfer ; export PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Could you expand on what each part of this does? A block of code like this isn't really self-explanatory to most users

Comment: @grgarside : Thank you for your suggestion. Please let me know if more explaination is required. Thanks again.

Comment: that will do it

Comment: How does this set the variable for GUI applications (started via Finder)?

Comment: @patrix : I'm not aware of the distinction in the many ways to set the environment variables for any particular layer of the System. The set of environment variables, as stated by OP, is system-wide. Presumably, if the GUI is using environment variables, it does so in the precise same manner as everything else. We don't have all the answers. We hope to have only at least working solutions.

Comment: patrix thx for the suggestion @user77732 see the changes and give this a try

Comment: @chillin - This is the issue in OSX environment variables **cannot** be set for GUIS and command line in the same way. In command line it is a simple edit of profile files GUI has to be done another way

Comment: @Mark : if you have any citation for this, or anything that mentions this, that there is something special about the GUI, and environment variables, I'd like to see it. System-wide variable definition should be exactly that... "System-wide." Granted, if it doesn't work, it doesn't work. That's all I got.

Comment: @chillin - Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/path_helper.8.html paths.d just for PATH