# Setting global/system variable visible from JVM in console and Eclipse

Tags: terminal, bash, launchd, java, eclipse

How to define global/system variable in OSX latest versions (Monterey/Ventura) that should be visible from console (JVM) and IDE (preferable Eclipse, IntelliJ has special knowledge how to handle this OSX riddle)?

I tried the following:

1. Classical .bashrc/.bash_profile file (`export foo=ABC`). It works fine
   for JVM in console, but not for Eclipse
2. `launchctl setenv foo ABC`. It doesn't work for both

I have very simple task - provide per laptop a path to a folder that must be accessible from development and test environments and the only option that I've is to define it twice :(

Comment: This question might help - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107787/57225