# Setting the system-wide PATH environment variable in Mavericks

Tags: macos, environment-variables

In previous OS versions one could set the system-wide PATH environment variable in `/etc/launchd.conf` to make it available for all apps (not just the command line).

In Mavericks this appears to be no longer used.

Is there another technique for doing this in mavericks?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### Yosemite

`/etc/launchd.conf` is no longer supported in 10.10. See `man launchctl`:

> The /etc/launchd.conf file is no longer consulted for subcommands to run during early boot time; this functionality was removed for security considerations.

You can now for example save this plist as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.startup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>launchctl setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The `launchctl setenv` command is ran as the user, so it only applies to processes launched in the user domain.

This method doesn't apply to applications that are reopened at login if "Reopen windows when logging back in" is checked.

### Mavericks and earlier

In 10.9 and earlier, you can for example run

```
echo setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin|sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf
```

and then restart to apply the changes.

### Other methods

`/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/` apply only (or mainly) to shells. The lines in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/*` are added to the path by [path_helper](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/path_helper.html), which is run from `/etc/profile`, `/etc/zshenv`, and `/etc/csh.login`. I don't know any programs other than shells that would consider `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d/`.

`~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` stopped working in 10.8.

Comment: Yep; it just doesn't exist by default but creating it and setting proper entries helps

Comment: On Yosemite, I found that some programs don't seem to see PYTHONPATH, which I have set in /etc/launchd.conf and I used your command line fix (the 2nd paragraph in your answer) and it doesn't seem to work, it just gives me the launchctl error/help message.

Comment: @Tango I edited the answer. `/etc/launchd.conf` was removed in 10.10.

Comment: I'll add that my experience, while playing around with bash, is that, on 10.10, launchctl setenv seems to do nothing.  I've tried setting env variables, then checked the value with echo and they were still undefined.

Comment: @Tango Quit and reopen your terminal application after running `launchctl setenv`. `launchctl setenv` has never affected existing processes.

Comment: Much appreciated!  I had no idea and that's an important point.

Comment: Note that applications started by "Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items" won't get the environment variables.

Comment: This is so terrible, but is the correct answer!  My god, Apple!  Why must you be so "friendly" to laymen while kicking developers in the crotch whenever possible?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/289060/setting-variables-in-environment-plist helps in case env is loaded

Comment: Could you update the answer for Catalina?

Comment: Just wonder how does it make it executed first before than other launch items?

Answer (score 12):

There is a much easier way. Place a text file in the folder `/etc/paths.d/`. In this text file, enter the desired path AND a newline. The best way is to create a new file for each path.

On my system, there is a file called MySQL with the text '/usr/local/mysql/bin' and a newline.

Comment: I've just posted [a new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126725/making-items-added-to-paths-via-paths-d-show-up-everywhere-under-mavericks) about whether there are ways to address the weakness described by @LauriRanta.

Comment: Just an anacdote: I have used this method as well, as it is the recommended "OS X way." I have not had much luck getting the System to honor consistently the PATH files I have in /etc/paths.d, and usually end up either using the export shell command, or placing my PATHs in ~/.bash_profile, which always work, if only for my current user account and not System-wide. If PATH files in /etc/paths.d always works for you, then I am jealous that your System is better behaved than mine ;)

Comment: This one is new for me. Nice!

Comment: Could you update the answer for Catalina?

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to set environment variables in the file `/etc/launchd-user.conf`...

In Mavericks, I was able to configure an environment variable in the file using the line:

```
setenv TEST test
```

After a fresh boot, `$TEST` from /etc/launchd-user.conf is set.

**Edit**

It's possible that the syntax of the file at /etc/launchd.conf is invalid. Can you post the contents of that file for examination?

From what I'm seeing, setting the PATH variable in /etc/launchd.conf is working normally. However, `launchd` does not perform any [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). Therefore, if you have an entry like `setenv PATH $PATH:/usr/local/bin`, your resulting path would be set to "`$PATH:/usr/local/bin`" (note: not the *value of* PATH, but the text "$PATH")

Comment: Thanks, the problem I'm having is setting the PATH, other environment variables seem to work.

Comment: @Tom - I've provided an additional suggestion above

Comment: is it really launch-user.conf or launch-[current_user_name].conf

Comment: /etc/launchd.conf containing 'setenv TEST test' does not propagate into Terminal on my Mavericks.

Comment: Oops: s/Mavericks/Yosemite/.

Comment: @DaveX I think that it's recommended to use `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d` to add new paths to your Terminal environment as described in the answer above (in the "Other methods" section.)

Comment: @Eddie Kelly: If you must use /etc/paths* for terminal and /etc/launchd* for non-terminal apps, then there isn't a single place to set a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

I found that `launchctl setenv PATH` still works for me for Terminal and applications, but broke in shell scripts, launched directly via clicking or Open With in Terminal from, say, Finder. It's very strange. Other environment variables from `/etc/launchd.conf` work.

In order to fix it for shell scripts launched directly, I also set up PATH either in `/etc/paths.d/*` or in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Where did you duplicate your `~/.bash_profile` PATH to? To the shell script itself?

Comment: I meant I copied PATHs from `/etc/launchd.conf` to `~/.bash_profile`. Now, with Catalina, I migrated this setup to set up PATH either in `/etc/paths.d/*` or in `~/.bashrc`, not in both. This works for all shell scripts. I also do `launchctl setenv PATH ...` on startup for GUIs. What I noticed is that it does not quite work for some GUIs.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

on my Mavericks install , adding "setenv PATH blablabla" to /etc/launchd.conf didn't work after reboot

so i added my new path to the end of /etc/paths , which worked.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I rebooted, `/etc/paths` contains everything I want and yet Sublime still sees only the original PATH. If I run it from terminal, it works.

Comment: The path_helper command in my /etc/profile uses /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d to overwrite any PATH that might have been set by /etc/launchd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Editing `/etc/paths.d` or using `.bash_profile` didn't worked for me, however as suggested from someone else (I actually came here for upvote his answer, but I couldn't find it again?!), I edited `/etc/paths` which works for me

In my case, I added android-tool `adb` and `android` to terminal commands with pointing to their sdk paths (`adb` has moved to another directory nowadays) which look like

```
/usr/local/bin
...
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platform-tools  //new entries
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools
```

Answer (score 0):

SWEET, adding that XML to ~/Library/LaunchAgents/setenv.SVN.plist allowed BBEdit to use the subversion binaries I installed in /opt.

```
<clip>
<string>launchctl setenv PATH /opt/subversion/bin:$PATH</string>
<clip>
```

Comment: Any idea how to determine if this file supports parameter expansion? I may have set the path so the one in /opt is the only one. And I'm thinking that it's likely it does NOT support using $PATH. How would you determine the existing path to begin with?

Answer (score -2):

Simply add your 'bin' (the path that you want to add) path to /etc/paths file - reboot or relogin !!!

```
sudo vi /etc/paths 
(create a file (paths file) if it does't exist, I am using 'vi' editor, you can use your own as super user )
then, add your bin directory path like below 

/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.3/bin
/usr/local/gradle-1.11/bin
```

save the file and relogin ... hope this helps