# Making items added to paths via paths.d show up everywhere under Mavericks

Tags: macos, launchd, path, environment-variables

I'd like to set the path under OS X Mavericks so that the setting shows up everywhere (e.g., in .apps and in Darwin shells). There's [plenty of discussion out there about how to set environment variables generally under OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion). With `environments.plist` [no longer supported by Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502061/2829764), it seems that [editing `/etc/launchd.conf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/2829764) is the best option for doing so. Unfortunately, [launchd.conf apparently does no parameter expansion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks/106372#106372), so I can't do this:

```
setenv PATH /Users/kuzzooroo/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

and I don't want to hardcode my entire path--it seems unmaintainable.

There's another question in AskDifferent specifically about [setting the system-wide PATH environment variable in Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks/106372#106372). The accepted solution is [to use `/etc/paths.d/`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106549/60655), but someone has posted the following comment (which has garnered several upvotes) as a caveat:

> Paths in paths.d are added to the path by path_helper, which is run from /etc/profile and /etc/csh.login, but not when for example bash is invoked as a non-interactive or non-login shell or when you run programs in text editors.

Is there a way I can make these environments pull in paths.d (for example, by putting a command to process paths.d into some bash configuration file that is run even for non-interactive shells)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: just use /etc/launchd.conf

Add a line like

```
setenv PATH /Users/username/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

to `/etc/launchd.conf` and restart to apply the changes.

The default path is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

`/etc/launchd.conf` applies to all processes, which includes graphical applications, non-login shells, and programs started by launchd jobs.

Edit `/etc/launchd.conf` manually if you see that some program or installer has added new paths to `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d/*`.

### Option 2: use a launchd job to set the path during startup

Save this plist as `/Library/LaunchDaemons/setpath.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>setpath</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>launchctl setenv PATH "$((launchctl getenv PATH|tr : \\n
    cat /etc/paths /etc/paths.d/*)|awk '!a[$0]++'|paste -sd: -)"</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The program should be run the next time you restart. It changes the `PATH` of the root `launchd` process, which is inherited by the user `launchd` process.

In my opinion it's easier to just edit `/etc/launchd.conf` though.

### Option 3: make bash run path_helper even for non-login shells

[path_helper](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/path_helper.html) is run from `/etc/profile`, `/etc/zshenv`, and `/etc/csh.login`. `zsh` reads `/etc/zshenv` even for non-login shells but `bash` does not read `/etc/profile` for non-login shells.

This makes `bash` run `path_helper` for interactive non-login shells and for non-interactive non-login shells:

```
echo 'eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)'>>~/.bashrc
setenv BASH_ENV /etc/profile|sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf
```

It does not make `bash` run `path_helper` for non-interactive non-login shells invoked as `sh`. It also does not affect graphical applications or processes that are not started from shells.