# Shell environment variables not available in GUI apps even if app launched via Command Line

Tags: terminal, macos

It is expected that shell environment variables won't be available in GUI apps launched via `Spotlight` or `Finder.app`.

But until Mavericks - I could launch an app via Command line such as:

```
open -a IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 11
```

And Intellij will inherit the environment variables defined in shell (In my case zsh). This does not seem to work properly anymore. I have seen similar problem, when I launch `Emacs.app` from command line.

Related thread -  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208181/why-did-my-tex-related-gui-program-stop-working-in-mac-os-x-yosemite

BTW, I know I can use [Setting the system-wide PATH environment variable in Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks) for setting system wide environment variables, but I don't want system wide environment variables. I want GUI app to inherit variables that were defined at the point, the app was launched from command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
launchctl setenv VARIABLE VALUE
open -a IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 11
launchctl unsetenv VARIABLE
```

This will pass environment variable `VARIABLE` into the launched app and later it will be cleaned, but will remain in the app.

Comment: Doesn't work in El Capitan. :(