# Setting path env variable in Yosemite 10.10.2 for a GUI app

Tags: macos

After upgrading to 10.10.2 when I lunch a GUI app from a terminal using `open -a app` the app doesn't see the path currently set from that terminal session. Before the upgrade that was working. Any idea what happened?

Comment: Have You tried this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152294/shell-environment-variables-not-available-in-gui-apps-even-if-app-launched-via-c?rq=1 ?

Comment: As he stated in a deleted comment in that thread : Apparently it does not work anymore in 10.10.2

Comment: No idea why my comment is deleted ... I've tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a known bug in 10.10. launchctl setenv can't set the $PATH. /etc/launchd.conf is deprecated and no longer works either. What app are you trying to set the $PATH for? I can try a few things later when I'm back at my Mac.

Comment: WebStorm/IntelliJ, I have a workaround for this to get Grunt working and some commands in embedded Terminal, but it used to be much easer to pick up everything from Terminal ...

Comment: The answer to "what happened" is that this appears to be an OS X bug, but is your question how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is a solution that affects all GUI apps acceptable?