# Setting variables in environment.plist

Tags: launchd, environment-variables

I've been trying to come to terms with how to set environment variables needed by launched applications in Sierra, but I'm puzzled.

Following various bits of advice found online, I created a file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist`.  It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.startup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>
      launchctl setenv FOO foo
      launchctl setenv BAR bar
      <!-- ... -->
      launchctl setenv PATH /usr/local/opt/scala210/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
    </string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

From my experimenting, it appears that nothing less than a system reboot will make changes to this file take effect.  I did find mentions of this command that will supposedly do the trick:

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
```

...but when I run it I get this response:

```
[my home dir]/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist: service already loaded
```

In the documentation for `launchctl` I see mention of a `-F` flag that seems relevant:

```
Force the loading or unloading of the plist. Ignore the Disabled key.
```

However, it makes no difference if I include this switch; I get the same output and the file is ignored.

So anyway, rebooting does make the changes take effect (maybe logging out and back in also would? I didn't check), but with one exception: the `PATH` variable.  That variable just stayed the same no matter how I changed it, and across reboots.  Eventually I stumbled across a Stack Exchange answer that offhandedly warned that changing `PATH` in this way would be ignored until the Dock was restarted with the `killall Dock` command.  So I did that, and rebooted, and **finally** I had my `PATH` set correctly.

So, anyway, I suppose my main question would be: Is there any more hassle-free way to update environment variables than the way I outline above?  And a subsidiary question might be: Does the special handling of `PATH` make any sense at all?

Comment: Launchd is very aggressive about staring things up in parallel.  So I have observed cases, during startup, where this LaunchAgent fired later than I'd like.  For example after my editor launched.  I'm of the impression this is more common if I'm rebooting and I took the kind offer to restart my current applications after the reboot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Unload the launch agent:

  ```
  launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
  ```
- Modify the plist/env settings
- Load the launch agent again:

  ```
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
  ```

---

You have to quit and relaunch Terminal to get the new value of the variable in the shell.

With the example of Kuldeep Yadav's [comment](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/kuldeepiitg/8nRq5G#file-Users/kuldeep/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist) the usr.aws.plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgent/ would look like this then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>usr.aws</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
                <string>setenv</string>
                <string>AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY</string>
                <string>loremipsum</string>
                <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
                <string>setenv</string>
                <string>AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID</string>
                <string>loremipsum2</string>
                <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
                <string>setenv</string>
                <string>AWS_ACCESS_KEY</string>
                <string>loremipsum3</string>
                <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
                <string>setenv</string>
                <string>AWS_SECRET_KEY</string>
                <string>loremipsum4</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is only tested (& working) with bash & zsh.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I launched Terminal; typed `echo $FOO`; saw `foo`; and exited Terminal.  Then I unloaded `environment.plist` with your `launchctl unload ...` command above, changed the command in that file to `launchctl setenv FOO bar`, saved the file, and loaded the file with your `launchctl load ...` command.  Finally I launched Terminal again, typed `echo $FOO`, and still saw the output `foo`.  ...Ah, if I kill and restart the dock with `killall Dock`, then launch Terminal again, I finally see the updated value of `FOO`.  Bloody hell, what a pain.

Comment: @Sean Now tested in Sierra and it also works. No need to reboot, or kill an app (except Terminal which has to be relaunched). I'll try to add a work-around or a better solution...

Comment: I am getting `Invalid or missing service identifier` on running `launchctl load .MacOSX/environment.plist`

Comment: @klanomath I still couldn't understand.

Comment: I added lines as per your recommendations in a file https://bitbucket.org/snippets/kuldeepiitg/8nRq5G#file-Users/kuldeep/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist but still not working. Can you please help with me the file?

Comment: @KuldeepYadav Updated the answer with your example. Move the file renamed to usr.aws.plist to ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ and load it with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/usr.aws.plist`

Comment: @klanomath which mac-os are you using? Because mine is still not working.

Comment: @KuldeepYadav The value of AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY won't be *loremipsum* I suppose ;-). I've tested it in 10.13.6. What's the version of your system?

Comment: haha I am just echoing it in terminal like: `echo $AWS_SECRET_KEY`, but prints nothing.

Comment: @klanomath can you please join chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103770/mac-environment-variables

Comment: This method, of a text plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents works for me, for interactive Mac applications. However, Terminal appears to clear the inherited environment. To see that this works, I used Xcode's **New Project** command to create a new mac App, and had it call `system("printenv");` M1 Monterey macOS 12.1

Comment: However, only the first pair of `<string>/bin/launchctl</string<string>setenv</string>` is needed. The later copies of that pair just create an environment variable named `/bin/launchctl` with value `setenv `