# Adding third-party C/C++ libraries to Xcode's path globally

Tags: macos, xcode, development, path

I added my `/usr/local/bin` and `/opt/homebrew/include` to my `CPATH` variable. This way the clang compiler recognizes libraries residing in these paths when invoked from command line. However, when I am to develop something in Xcode, Xcode (12.5.1) doesn't recognize these paths unless explicitly added to Xcode project settings. As you may have experienced, doing so is really troublesome.

I want these paths added to `CPATH` to be globally available to all C/C++ projects in Xcode in Big Sur (11.6) M1 Macs without having to explicitly add them in each project settings.

Is it possible?

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/106355/30895.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks but I need an up-to-date explanation.

Comment: Really you don't want this you need to control by project. Also your first sentence is confusing - libraries are in neither of those directories. header files will be in the latter.

Comment: My general experience in C programmimg is that you want all your environment information in your build scripts and no in your environment as you can't show whet was used to build the code. (Given how Apple have removed the easy setting of environment variables seems to be their choice as well)

Comment: @mmmmmm Can you show an example of how a build script for a C/C++ Xcode project should be? Never done it before.

Comment: For Xcode it is the Xcode project . I meant Xcode or Eclipse or Visual Studio project or Makefile or any other build tool. You then have all the build information under version control and also can move the project between machines etc

Comment: The best way might be to produce Xcode project templates which have the paths in them. Then new projects will have the paths in