# Apple Script can't find executables

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, zsh

Since moving to `zsh` from `bash` my previous AppleScript scripts can no longer find executables that are in my path, unless I use the full path to the executables.

What can I do to keep using `zsh` and stop having to enter the full path to the executable in my AppleScript scripts?

I feel like I am missing some configuration setup for `zsh` or for AppleScript.

```
11/05/21_14:20:53 /Users/john
$ mypath
/Users/john/.pyenv/shims
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

example script was not working:

```
do shell script "pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g' | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pbcopy"
```

working with full paths to execs:

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/pbpaste | /usr/local/bin/gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g' | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pbcopy"
```

Would it have anything to do with running these scripts under `bash` first. `sh` does know where the executables are.

```
sh-3.2$ which gsed
/usr/local/bin/gsed
sh-3.2$ which pbpaste
/usr/bin/pbpaste
sh-3.2$
```

EDIT_1: From Apple Technical Note TN2065

> Second, when you use just a command name instead of a complete path,
> the shell uses a list of directories (known as your PATH) to try and
> find the complete path to the command. For security and portability
> reasons, do shell script ignores the configuration files that an
> interactive shell would read, so you don’t get the customizations you
> would have in Terminal. Use the full path to the command, for example,
> /sbin/ifconfig instead of just ifconfig. To find the full path in
> Terminal, say which command-name, for example, which ifconfig; to see
> the list of places do shell script will search, say do shell script
> "echo $PATH".

Still don't understand why all of these scripts worked without the full path when `bash` was my default shell and are all broken now that `zsh` is my default.

EDIT_2 THIS!

> Where does the shell environment come from — environment variables,
> working directory, and so on? do shell script inherits the environment
> of its parent process, which is always the process running the script.
> The environment covers the working directory, any environment
> variables, and several other attributes — see execve(2) for a complete
> list. As mentioned in Issuing Commands, do shell script does not read
> the configuration files that an interactive shell running in Terminal
> would.
>
> Any application launched from the Finder gets the same default
> environment: a working directory of / and the environment variables
> HOME, LANG, PATH, SHELL, and USER. Most applications do not change
> their environment, but relying on this is a maintenance risk.

Comment: Because however you are invoking these scripts does not set the path you think it does.  What IS the path while one of these is running?  Where do you set your path and how are you invoking these scripts?

Comment: The default `PATH` passes to the _shell_ in a `do shell script` _command_ is: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` -- So if the executable is not within that `PATH` you need to use the _fully qualified pathname_ or will need to preface the _command(s)_ with an `export PATH=\"...\";` where `...` represents the `PATH` you want to use . E.g.: `do shell script "export PATH=\"...\"; pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g' | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pbcopy"`

Comment: I see. Looking at Apple Technical Note TN2065 has some info. I am invoking it using Script Editor in the Finder Menu bar. My paths are set in both `.bash_profile` and `.zprofile`. I guess I am confused because this wasn't an issue until I moved to `zsh`. Do Apple Script scripts store paths in metadata when they are created?

Comment: RE: "Do Apple Script scripts need to be "rehashed"?" --  What do you mean, what are you asking here?

Comment: @user3439894 the shell can store paths to recently used commands. I was pondering on that. Wondering if since I ran the script under bash and it worked it may have hashed the paths,,, but that makes no sense. The paths haven't changed. I added more to the post.

Comment: Each invocation of `do shell script` uses a new shell process, so state such as changes to variables and the working directory is not saved from one to the next.

Comment: @user3439894 I added more information in the original post. Something seems off. `do shell script` uses `sh` and `sh` knows where the executables are. Like I said, these scripts never required the full path to run before and some of the executables were/are not in the system default paths.

Comment: Not a single person can answer the question yet they are happy to mark it down. What has changed between moving from `bash` to `zsh` that would cause the same script to be unable to find an exec? Can't answer but willing to mark it down?

Comment: Changing your preferred interactive shell doesn't have anything to do with it.  Your example script is no doubt finding pbpaste just fine but not finding gsed.  Aside... is there some reason you need to use GNU sed?

Comment: The `do shell script` _command_ runs a **non-interactive non-login shell** using /bin/sh to interpret your command(s). If you run `do shell script "set"` you will see what you are working with.

Comment: @MarcWilson I answered your questions in the third comment

Comment: @MarcWilson, I am only talking about the `do shell script` _command_ run from **Script Editor**, or from a **Run AppleScript** _action_ in **Automator**.

Comment: What is in `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`? You can also run `do shell script "env"` to see what is set, SHELL should be pointing at zsh. You can set your path in ~/.profile and it should get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've done something highly creative, Script Editor is using `sh` to run shell scripts.  It does not use your configured shell.

That points to a copy of `bash` by default.

When `bash` is invoked (as a login shell) as `sh`, it only reads /etc/profile and ~/.profile.  But it reads no startup files otherwise.  So it is not reading any shell configuration you think you are providing.

So you should be just inheriting from the system.
[image]
Note that `pbpaste` is findable since it's in /usr/bin and the default path includes /usr/bin.

Since that doesn't work, something else has been changed.

Comment: What shell does do shell script use, really?
do shell script always calls /bin/sh. However, in macOS, /bin/sh is really bash emulating sh.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks/106814#106814

Comment: Which is irrelevant, when it's invoked as `sh` it is reading no startup files at all, it is simply inheriting the system environment.

Comment: Well... They clearly worked when I created them and used them for a year before I moved to `zsh`. The clearly don't work now. That's the conundrum and why I posted. I will keep working on what changed to cause this.