# How do I set environment variables on OS X?

Tags: terminal, bash, environment-variables

I have always difficulties setting the Environment variables in OS X like `JAVA_HOME`, `M2_HOME` or `PATH`. How to set these on OS X Mavericks?

I did some research but the answers I've found didn't really help me yet:

1. `export JAVA_HOME=/...` (But it seems that the changes are temporary, just for one terminal session.)
2. `setenv JAVA_HOME=/...` (But command not found.)
3. Open `.profile` and write the variables inside to make the changes permanent- (`.profile` does not exist).
4. Open `.bash_profile` and write the variables inside to make the changes permanent- (`.bash_profile` does not exist).
5. `vi ~/.bash_profile` (Quite a challenge for somebody who doesn't know `vi`.)
6. Creating your own `enrivonment.plist` file.

Can somebody please walk me through the steps to get that to work on OS X Mavericks, assuming *no* Unix knowhow?

Comment: For macOS Catalina and greater (Mojave, Catalina, Big Sur) you have to set them inside `~/.zshrc` as shown [here](https://mamk2118.medium.com/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-mojave-and-mac-os-catalina-27ea1bb032f3).

Comment: related on Stack Overflow: [Setting environment variables on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/11107541)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I have a `.profile` in my home directory; it contains many `export …` statements for environment variables.

You can create such a file by opening a Terminal and issuing the command `touch .profile`.

Close Terminal.

Then you should open that file in a plain-text editor (TextWrangler for example). You can also use `nano .profile` in a Terminal window (current directory should be your home), which is much easier than `vi`. Insert lines such as `export JAVA_HOME=…`. Save, exit `nano` if you used that and quit a running Terminal.

Open Terminal and issue the command `env` to see all environment variables. Check that the ones you defined have the value you assigned to them. You should be good to go now but don't forget that environment variables defined in `.profile` are not passed to GUI applications.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was what i really looking for. I now have set all my variables. What do u mean by GUI applications? I just needed some variables for java and maven in order to work with eclipse, spring tools etc. Eclipse is an application with GUI (Graphical User Interface). Do you mean this by GUI?

Comment: Ok. I have read some and i think you have mean really GUI with GUI.. Is there a way to make these variables available everywhere? What is the most common way or where is the most common location to define them then?

Comment: 1. yes that is what I meant by a GUI app. 2. setting environment variables for GUI app's in OS X 10.8 appears to be quit difficult. Some apps let you define environment variables, which are to be passed to other applications, in their preferences for example. You can also use the `open -a Appname` method in a Terminal session.

Comment: I don't know why but for me (OS X Yosemite 10.10.1) the `.profile` didn't help. I had to put the `export` statements into the `.bash_profile` to make it work. Hopefully this helps someone else if he runs into the same problems...

Comment: @chuky if you're using zsh you should add them to `.zprofile` instead.

Answer (score 46):

In case you're using `zsh` like me, you need to modify `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.zprofile` as sugguested by @timetofly).

Comment: Or in `.zprofile`

Comment: Some of my application add something to PATH, but I didn't see the `~/.zshrc` or `.zprofile` you said? @timetofly

Comment: You can try creating that file in your home directory and see if zsh picks it up.

Comment: Starting with macOS Catalina, Macs use zsh as the default login shell and interactive shell - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

Comment: what if I have both `.zshrc` & `.zprofile`, where do I set my new _environment variable_ ?

Comment: @Sumax you can have a try.

Answer (score 38):

In Yosemite, you should put `export VARIABLE='something'` inside `.bash_profile`.

I've tried writing the `export VARIABLE='something'` inside `.profile` without success.

Comment: if you're using zsh you should add them to `.zprofile` instead.

Answer (score 35):

From http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac:

- Open Terminal
- Run `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile`
- In TextEdit, add

  ```
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  ```
- Save the .bash_profile file and Quit (Command + Q) Text Edit.
- Run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This assumes that the user is using Bash as their shell. It will not work for alternative shells such as Fish Shell.

Comment: Your example in particular only shows how to extend the $PATH variable by a custom path. You can create your own unique environment variable by `export <variable name>='<variable value>'` in your shell's startup text file.

Answer (score 11):

For adding a directory to a path, there is a better option in OS X:
All entries in the file /etc/paths are added to the path, before any shell is started.

Edit this file with:

```
sudo pico /etc/paths
```

For more info, see: https://gist.github.com/Overbryd/1669348

Comment: Thank you! for me this is the most elegant way to include a new path

Answer (score 11):

```
launchctl setenv environmentvariablename environmentvariablevalue
```

or

```
launchctl setenv environmentvariablename `command that will generate value`
```

use proper ` and remember to restart application or terminal for the environment variable to take effect.

you can check environment variable by printenv command.

Comment: it works! in VSC you have to close all windows to actually restart the terminal.

Comment: This is the only answer (to date) that will set the environment variable for all shells _AND_ for applications!  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

For those who don't like to have the hassle with text files and editors, there is a [GUI tool as well on GitHub](https://github.com/hschmidt/EnvPane).

Comment: Great ! I spent whole day figuring out to solve the environment variable issue and I was nowhere .The app that you posted solved all my environment hassles

Answer (score 5):

OSX has had only one change re environment variables and that was in Lion where ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist was removed. Although there also has been a change in the default shell in 10.2 or 10.3 from tsch to bash.

You need to define what you want the enviroment variable set for and what environment you have.

You also need to understand shells and Unix which by your comments you have not fully done. There are several nbash tutorials around.

As to your points

1. You understand correctly assuming you are in a sh type shell (e.g. bash or zsh)
2. This is for C shells e.g. tcsh so won't work on recent defaults.
3. You need to create .profile then it works
4. It is .bash_profile or better .bashrc and you need to create the file first
5. Totally correct :) Use TextEdit or nano (or emacs)
6. Correct up to OSX 10.7 and the wy to do this for programs called from the Workspace e.g. from Dock or Finder (or open)

So 3 or 4 work if you are calling the program from the command line (or from a program started in the command line but not by open)

As for programs from the GUI see this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57385/where-are-system-environment-variables-set-in-mountain-lion?rq=1)

As for internet is full of rubbish - you need to have enough background to understand an article because as you have discovered many assume things or are incorrect. StackExhnage sites should be better as you can see if an answer has been agreed to from the number of votes.

Comment: I still do not have any result. The linked question does not bring me to solution. I have a mac for 4 years, yet still do not have (didn't have to) experience about UNIX. I think, when the answer of "Why is it damn so hard?" is "plist was removed, change in 10.2 or 10.3, sh type shell, up to 10.7 etc.." the answer contradicts with itself.

Comment: It could be made very easily like in windows. Anyway.. what i was really expecting was sth. like this: 1- open home dir 2- open terminal 3- write "xxx" 4-click save etc.. one must not have enough background to set just a simple variable, at least could find a proper solution from those boilerplate answers on the internet.

Comment: If you need environment variables you have to understand what they are doing and that requires background. Also as you did not state what you were using the variables for I have to give all the possible differences. Note for Java setting JAVA_HOME is not necessarily the best way (see Java questions)

Comment: My question was about SETTING the variables. Neither about what they are doing, nor about any other thing which requires more info. You can obviously set them even without background. Thank you for your answer though. But as i already wrote, a simple proposal for solution was enough, which i already have thanks to Bhas.

Comment: You really should not set variables without background you have to know what they do

Answer (score -1):

## Background Knowledge

- `Mac`'s `OS`=`Operation System`

  - old ones called: `OS X`

    - such as your `OS X Mavericks`
  - now called: `macOS`
- for any macOS, normally have built-in a console application, called `Terminal`

  - look like this (My here is Chinese name: `终端`)

    - [image]

> Can somebody please walk me through the steps to get that to work on OS X Mavericks, assuming no Unix knowhow?

## Steps to add environment variable in MacOS

### Simple

- use terminal to add `export JAVA_HOME=/your/path` to your launch script

  - `bash`'s `~/.bash_profile`
  - or `zsh`'s `~/.zshrc`

### Detail

#### open terminal

`Launch Pad` -> `Terminal`

look like this:

[image]

#### prepare boot script

then make sure you already have your boot script

for basic and common case is:

you are using bash, related boot script is `~/.bash_profile`

```
➜  ~ ls -lh ~/.bash_profile 
-rw-r--r--  1 crifan  staff   461B 10 28  2021 /Users/crifan/.bash_profile
```

if can not found, you can create one:

`touch ~/.bash_profile`

#### add your environment variable into your boot script

then you can edit the boot script `~/.bash_profile`

using text editor, such as `vi` / `vim` / `nano` / `echo`

here use most simple:

`echo "export JAVA_HOME=/your/path" >> ~/.bash_profile`

here is my output for you refer:

(using `cat` to print file content to verify is ok)

```
➜  ~ cat ~/.bash_profile 
export THEOS=/opt/theos
export PATH=$PATH:$THEOS/bin

export THEOS_MAKE_PATH=$(THEOS)/makefiles
export THEOS_BIN_PATH=$(THEOS)/bin
export THEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=$(THEOS)/lib
export THEOS_VENDOR_LIBRARY_PATH=$(THEOS)/vendor/lib
export THEOS_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/include
export THEOS_VENDOR_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/vendor/include
export THEOS_FALLBACK_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/include/_fallback
export THEOS_MODULE_PATH=$(THEOS)/mod
export THEOS_SDKS_PATH=$(THEOS)/sdks

➜  ~ echo "export JAVA_HOME=/your/path" >> ~/.bash_profile 
➜  ~ cat ~/.bash_profile                                  
export THEOS=/opt/theos
export PATH=$PATH:$THEOS/bin

export THEOS_MAKE_PATH=$(THEOS)/makefiles
export THEOS_BIN_PATH=$(THEOS)/bin
export THEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=$(THEOS)/lib
export THEOS_VENDOR_LIBRARY_PATH=$(THEOS)/vendor/lib
export THEOS_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/include
export THEOS_VENDOR_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/vendor/include
export THEOS_FALLBACK_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/include/_fallback
export THEOS_MODULE_PATH=$(THEOS)/mod
export THEOS_SDKS_PATH=$(THEOS)/sdks

export JAVA_HOME=/your/path
➜  ~
```

#### [optional] make variable take effect immediately

normally above is ok. but if you want to let your added environment variable take effect immediately, you can use:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

then can use `echo` to verify worked

```
➜  ~ source ~/.bash_profile 
....
➜  ~ echo $JAVA_HOME
/your/path
```

### appendix

the full log for refer:

```
➜  ~ ls -lh ~/.bash_profile 
-rw-r--r--  1 crifan  staff   461B 10 28  2021 /Users/crifan/.bash_profile
➜  ~ cat ~/.bash_profile 
export THEOS=/opt/theos
export PATH=$PATH:$THEOS/bin

export THEOS_MAKE_PATH=$(THEOS)/makefiles
export THEOS_BIN_PATH=$(THEOS)/bin
export THEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=$(THEOS)/lib
export THEOS_VENDOR_LIBRARY_PATH=$(THEOS)/vendor/lib
export THEOS_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/include
export THEOS_VENDOR_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/vendor/include
export THEOS_FALLBACK_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/include/_fallback
export THEOS_MODULE_PATH=$(THEOS)/mod
export THEOS_SDKS_PATH=$(THEOS)/sdks

➜  ~ echo "export JAVA_HOME=/your/path" >> ~/.bash_profile 
➜  ~ cat ~/.bash_profile                                  
export THEOS=/opt/theos
export PATH=$PATH:$THEOS/bin

export THEOS_MAKE_PATH=$(THEOS)/makefiles
export THEOS_BIN_PATH=$(THEOS)/bin
export THEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=$(THEOS)/lib
export THEOS_VENDOR_LIBRARY_PATH=$(THEOS)/vendor/lib
export THEOS_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/include
export THEOS_VENDOR_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/vendor/include
export THEOS_FALLBACK_INCLUDE_PATH=$(THEOS)/include/_fallback
export THEOS_MODULE_PATH=$(THEOS)/mod
export THEOS_SDKS_PATH=$(THEOS)/sdks

export JAVA_HOME=/your/path
➜  ~ source ~/.bash_profile 
...
➜  ~ echo $JAVA_HOME
/your/path
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also how does it improve on other answers. Also either the OP wants to chnage things in the terminal which then makes most of this answer not useful as they know how to get to terminal or the OP wants to set variables for a GUI app and in that case you do not answer.

Answer (score -1):

`.bash_profile` works for bash but not for zsh that is used by default in macOS.

Since you may need both, I encourage to create symbolic link:

`ln -s ~/.bash_profile .zprofile`

Answer (score -1):

In Terminal, type this (without any spaces around = sign)

```
export PORT=5000
```

Comment: That is the first point in the question - how is this an answer?

Answer (score -2):

Open terminal

**COMMAND-1**

input : echo $SHELL
output : /bin/zsh

if your machine uses zsh then use below commands|

**Command - 2**

vi ~/.zshrc

it will open new file or edits existing file.

now add below line and press esc and enter :wq to save and close the file.
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

**Command 3::** to apply the changes

source ~/.zshr

**Command 4::**

echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

you will see output as per above line.