# Mac OS X Mavericks - add to path

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

I'm trying to set up a phonegap project and while trying to add a platform it outputs the following error:

```
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
```

I've tried what I've read here: [How do I set environment variables on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x)

and wrote the following in the .profile file:

```
export PATH=/users/ophir/android-sdks/tools
```

while it did add the android command to my path and I was able to run it and get a response, I started noticing that a simple "ls" command suddenly didn't work - until I removed what I have done.

how can I add another path to the PATH variable? how does it all work on OS X anyhow?

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your command replaces the entire path variable with your path, thereby removing folders such as /bin. You need to add your path to the existing path, not replace it:

```
export PATH=/users/ophir/android-sdks/tools:$PATH
```

Alternatively, so that you don't replace the tools found in folders that are in your existing path, you can add your new folder to the end of the path variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/users/ophir/android-sdks/tools
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. how can I add more then one path? delimit with ; ?

Comment: @developer82 Delimit with `:` — `/path/1:/path/2:$PATH`

Comment: Yes, delimit the different paths with ':'. I also like to add the new path to the end rather than the beginning so I do `export PATH=$PATH:/users/ophir/android-sdks/tools` - it means you can't accidentally replace one of the system tools as they will be found first.

Comment: @grgarside i got this error "An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 
/bin/sh: /Users/****/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/create: No such file or directory"